# Inserting data using Hibernate Template

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider the following:

> User.java

```
class User{
    ...
    private Set<Community> communities = new HashSet<Community>();
    ...
}
```

> Community.java

```
class Community{
    ...
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
    ...
}
```

> User.hbm.xml

```
<set name="communities" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" table="tbl_user_community">
        <key column="user_id" />
        <many-to-many class="Community" column="community_id"/>
     </set>
```

> Community.hbm.xml

```
<set name="users" lazy="false" cascade="save-update" table="tbl_user_community" inverse="true">
    <key column="community_id" />
    <many-to-many class="User" column="user_id"/>
</set>
```

both has `many-to-many` relationship.

Code for adding community to user:

```
HibernateTemplate template = null;
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
template = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);

User user = template.get(User.class, "100");
Community community = template.get(Community.class,1);



user.getCommunities().add(community);


template.saveOrUpdate(user);
```

Scenario:

> 1. community1 is assigned to user1 (inserted into database)
> 2. community2 is assigned to user1 (inserted into database)
> 3. community1 is assigned to user2 (inserted into database)
> 4. community2 is assigned to user2 (not inserted into database, throws `NonUniqueObjectException`)
> 5. if i use `template.merge(user)` instead of `template.saveOrUpdate(user)`.. it works .. why???

Comment: Show us the code triggering the exception, and the complete exception stack trace. But you don't need to call neither saveOrUpdate(), nor merge(). Attached entities are persistent objects. They're persisted automatically, transparently.

Comment: exception is triggered at `template.saveOrUpdate(user)` and exception: `Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.mycompany.entity.Community#2]`

Answer (score 0):

`saveOrUpdate()` and `update()` take a detached object and attach this object instance to the session. So if an entity with the same type and ID is already attached to the session, Hibernate can't attach another instance: it would break the guarantee that only one entity with a given ID exists in a session. So it throws this exception.

`merge()` is different. It takes an detached entity, loads the entity with the same ID in the session if not already loaded, and copies the state (i.e. the fields) of the detached entity to the attached one. The detached entity stays deteached and unmodified.

So, in general, `merge()` should be preferred. BTW, the other methods don't exist in the JPA API. If you use saveOrUpdate(), you should generally call it as the first instruction of the transaction, to avoid being in the situation causing the NonUniqueException.